# Make [piglatin] a synonym of [pig]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Having a completely separate tag for Pig Latin is unnecessary hair splitting just because it is the ['textual layer'](http://pig.apache.org/):

> Apache Pig is a platform for analyzing large data sets that consists of a high-level language for expressing data analysis programs, coupled with infrastructure for evaluating these programs. [...]
>
> Pig's language layer currently consists of a textual language called Pig Latin [...]

Already 438/490 (~89%) of all questions in [piglatin](/questions/tagged/piglatin) are also tagged with [pig](/questions/tagged/pig).

**Update:** It is hard for me to put this into words since the distinction between the two is something like the distinction between actual written python code E.G. `print 'foo'` and the language as a whole. Since there is no such distinction for other languages, I don't think there should be for Pig.

---

**Note:** I'm keeping the above part to explain the downvotes/show the history.

After sleeping on it and rereading the posts I understand what is going on now.  I've only ever worked with languages where the underlying technology and textual language were closely linked (e.g. Python), so I wasn't thinking of it like SQL. Further, my team always calls 'pig latin' just 'pig'.

Anyways, now that I've defended my honor...

So, should questions about pig latin E.G. [Understanding Map Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772308/), be retagged to remove [pig](/questions/tagged/pig)? Should questions like [PIG_HOME environment variable in a pig latin script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388935) be retagged to remove [piglatin](/questions/tagged/piglatin)?  You can also write user-defined-functions (UDFS) in Python and Java, which can then be imported and used in pig latin scripts.  How should these questions be tagged?

Basically, what is the next step?

Comment: but not vice-versa... i.e. are all pig questions about piglatin?

Comment: @hayd I've updated my question with an example about why I think they are.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Shouldn't a **Nay** answer be upvoted, not the question downvoted?

Comment: @Jim [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Jim you could very easily argue that the question shows little or no research effort (they clearly haven't even read the [pig tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pig/info) to understand that pig and piglatin are most certainly not syonyms), in spite of the fact that this is meta and this is typically how we express disagreement with proposals or feature requests.

Comment: @Aaron I have read the tag wikis for both pig and pig latin. I guess that I'm just confused about the difference. Regardless, is there I way I can show I concede the point? E.G. Delete the question (which I know I can't do).

Comment: @mr2ert pig latin is a language. Pig is a database-related technology. I think you are still failing to grasp that the whole reason you are asking for these to be a synonym is based on the false pretense that people tagging questions pig and piglatin were doing so correctly. They weren't. Change the question to a request to clean up the piglatin questions that were incorrectly tagged with pig.

Comment: @Aaron Sorry, I thought that I made it clear in my last comment that I understand that I'm just confused about it all.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes, that's just meta. *Really* we are happy you care about the site.

Comment: The 2 examples are correct interpretations. About the user-defined function, probably case-by-case (since you didn't give a specific question, it is hard to talk about tagging)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I disagree. Not all [pig](/questions/tagged/pig) questions involve the language.

For example, questions about downloading, building, installing, configuring, system requirements, API, unit testing, etc. do not have anything to do with the language layer, and therefore should only be tagged `pig`. This is probably why the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pig/info) says nothing about `piglatin`.

You could argue that the reverse is not true: all `piglatin` questions ultimately have to involve the underlying technology of `pig`. But to me, this is not enough to make the former a synonym of the latter. Why do we need to force the language to mean the same thing as the platform when they clearly do not, and the dependency you assert does not flow in both directions? The same reason we don't make `t-sql` a synonym of `sql-server`, `plsql` a synonym for `oracle`, or `word` a synonym for `office`. A lot of SQL Server questions involve transact-sql, naturally, but not all of them do.

In essence, just because one technology can't live without the other, does not make them the same or even interchangeable. I will confess that I did not go through them, but there are likely questions out there currently that are tagged both `pig` and `piglatin` that only really need to be tagged one or the other. If a question about the language is not tagged with `pig` as well, do you think people would be confused about which `piglatin` they meant? Ou-day ou-yay eally-ray?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've updated my question with an example (which is probably a better explanation about why I think they should be synonyms), could you please address it?

Comment: @mr2ert I don't know how to address your update, except you seem to be confusing the fact that people tagged `piglatin` questions incorrectly with `pig` and the fact that there is an entire database-related technology called pig which is completely unrelated and deserves its own tags. Have you really looked at the tag wiki, and have you perused some questions tagged pig but *not* piglatin? These are not synonyms, they are just victims of users thinking they are.

Comment: Can you think of an example where one would tag [pig] and not [piglatin] (or vice-versa)?

Comment: @nhahtdh what if we're buying something with pigs (like cows in India)?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I can't imagine how that is related to my question.

Comment: @nhahtdh well, completely unrelated might be a bit of an overstatement, but I can certainly envision questions about pig that have nothing to do with the language, and not sure I agree that all piglatin questions need to also be tagged pig. Should we make tsql a synonym for sql-server? How about making Word a synonym for Office? Just because one technology can't exist without another doesn't make them synonyms.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Since Pig platform is quite new, I understand that the language and the platform are always seen together, which may not be the case in the long run if some other language is developed for Pig platform (from my limited understanding). Just that it is also necessary to draw a line when [pig] or [piglatin] is used, similar to how we draw a line between [tsql] and [sql-server].

Comment: @nhahtdh so "always seen together" means you can't have questions about downloading, building, installing, configuring, system requirements, API, unit testing, etc.? Why do we need to force the language to mean the same thing as the platform when they clearly do not? A lot of SQL Server questions involve T-SQL, but not all of them. This seems similar, and that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I don't disagree with the point that they are different, but my point is how to differentiate between them. Either way, your comment explain how the tags should be used. (Do you mind including them in your answer?)

Comment: @nhahtdh suitable update?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've slept on this, so now I feel that I (hopefully) have a grasp on what is going on now. I've updated my question to reflect this.  What is the next step? It wouldn't be very hard for me to help enact whatever changes need to be made as I continue to answer questions in the tags.

Comment: @mr2ert I don't know what the next step is, or if there needs to be one. (If you find a question that isn't tagged correctly, re-tag it.) I just know that the solution was not to make these two tags synonyms.

Comment: I think we should decide/know what we should support here, either theory or practice. The answer is absolutely correct from the theory point of view, but not useful form the practice point of view. In practice I noticed that many questions are tagged with both pig and piglatin, sometimes incorrectly. And many times people just forget to put piglatin instead of / with pig.